# Setting bitmap as window background

Tags: android, bitmapdrawable

I want to set a `BitmapDrawable` as background for a window of a particular activity. But I recently read that drawables are not easily collected by the Garbage Collector. So is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not heard that.  People do it all the time.  I have backdrops in almost ALL of my apps.  I even have apps where the backdrop changes throughout the lifecycle.  Never had a problem with it.